# Is it possible to create new repositories on jazz server?

Tags: repository, rtc, ibm-jazz, ibm-rational

Is it possible to create new repositories(other than the default /ccm/, /qm/, /rm) on jazz server so that it can be connected using rtc (repository connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Configuring the Jazz Team Server and the first application after the upgrade](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_update_jazz_setup_after_upgrade.html&scope=null), those `/ccm/, /qm/, /rm` are "applications", not "repositories".

You can [register a new application](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.jazz.repository.web.admin.doc/topics/t_register.html&scope=null) (in addition of the applications running on a common Jazz Team Server: Requirements Management (RM), Change and Configuration Management (CCM), Quality Management (QM), and Design Management (DM))

An example would be the [Rational Git Adapter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rliahelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.rlia.git.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_gitovr.html), with its url:

```
https://fully qualified hostname:port/gitAdapter.
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that they are application and not repositories.